# How to regex part of a string from and to some certain characters

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following string and I want to find a proper regex for it, so I can use it in Regular Expression in Jmeter:

```
DocumentId_123456
```

The point is that every time the numbers have different length. 
so basically I want everything between `_` and the end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try  it, I guess it works in jmeter**

```
DocumentId_(\d+)
```

Uou can check it here: [https://regex101.com/]